# Feasability report and the kickoff meeting

Tags: software-development, waterfall

Is feasability study related to kick off meeting?

My understanding is that the feasability study is done before the contracts are signed to ensure that the project is 'feasible'.

But my question is that, is there a need to mention/present the feasibility report in the kickoff meeting? What is the norm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct in that the feasibility study would be completed before the project formally begins. It's the document that evaluates whether the project can be successful and whether it should be undertaken. That definitely needs to happen before you've formally started the project with the kick-off meeting.

You could reference the feasibility study if you wanted to ensure that the project team was aware of the findings of the report. You could also make it available to them as part of the project documentation to be reviewed. It's not necessarily a requirement for a successful kick-off meeting, though. A lot of the decision would depend on who is in the room for your kick-off meeting.

In my organization, we tend to have two kick-off meetings -- one for the steering committee/high-level stakeholders, who may be more interested in the overall feasibility of the project, and one for the project team who needs to be formally brought into the project so they can start working. That may be something to look into for your project.

Answer (score 1):

Feasibility study gives a clear idea to all the project members the viability of going ahead with the project. Everyone involved with the project would be aware of the background of that particular project.